# Toshiba satellite L500 no Wifi anymore!

Tags: wireless, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Satellite L500 with Ubuntu 12.04 and its wifi suddenly stopped working!! I've never seen like that before.. I tried also using external USB wifis but no success. I am not able to turn it on with the function keys nor using rfkill commands and similar WLAN manipulator Commands in the terminal! It was working before for at least 4-5 months!! 
The computer says it's turned off by hardware. I checked it and the Driver is fine. So why can i not use any Wifi on my computer?? Why it is suddenly disabled? I checked the BIOS too there is enabled the WLAN. I spent 10 hours for searching for solutions but i am out of ideas!!! Please Help!

UPDATE: I have no wifi since i installed the following updates:

- bind9-host
- dnsutils
- libdns81
- libisccc80
- liblwres80
- libbind9-80
- libisccfg82
- libisc83
- freeglut3 (i think this one can be ignored)

If i try to downgrade this updates in Synaptic, it wants to delete some packages like: gnome-nettool, ubuntu-desktop etc.

Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix of the same issue I was facing a few months back on a Toshiba Satellite L510 laptop with Ubuntu 11.04. I hope this helps.

You can try to do so by following below mentioned steps:
(1) Please try to install 'ndisgtk' (to use windows driver on ubuntu)

> sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common
>   sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

(2) Download relevant Realtek wireless driver
(http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/p...Level=4&Conn=3)

(3) Install/Browse Realtek Drivers by opening ndiswrapper/windows wireless driver app & confirm it shows 'Hardware Present=Yes"

(4) Run following commands in terminal:

> ndiswrapper -l
>   ndiswrapper -m
>   ifconfig wlan0 up
>   ifconfig

Now try to connect with wireless from network manager/wicd UI.

Comment: I can't install this Driver because my system already has one and it is "working" This is not a driver issue i guess. Maybe BIOS....